# Se puede cambiar el diseño de navigator.notification.alert de apache cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, apache-cordova

Estoy trabajando con apache cordova, pero las alertas del plugin dialogs no se ve muy estético.

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, "Verificar","Aceptar");
```

Comment: y que has investigado o intentado para hacerlo custom???

Comment: la respuesta es si se puede ...

Comment: Me podrías decir como, o pasarme un link, porfa.

Comment: no hacemos investigaciones por los usuarios ... eso es algo que cada uno debe hacer por su cuenta

Comment: te sugiero que hagas el  [tour] para que comprendas mejor como funciona el sitio.